# AVR or PIC? Using MATLAB

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

well, i have to use a microcontroller that will decide the further course of action of a robot,that is continuously capturing images,with an on board camera and using MATLAB to process those images.(in a competition).Which microcontroller should i go for? The AVR series or PIC?i know to use 8051 microcontroller, but now i have to interface the AVR or PIC microcontroller with MATLAB. Can anybody help?

Comment: For image processing you probably need something more powerful than an 8 bit controller.

Answer (score 2):

They're about equal in terms of power and options.  You'll always be able to find what you need in either line of uC's.  I prefer AVR for their better development tools and community support at places like AVRFreaks.  You can find cheap boards and cheap programmers and tons of app notes for AVR.  It's probably the easier to develop for.  Plus, free C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the development process, I agree with Stephen Friederichs. The main question is: How do you communicate with MATLAB?

- using a [serial interface](http://www.mathworks.ch/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/serial.html) like a
  COM port?
- using ethernet?
- compiling a
  custom [MATLAB function](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/mex.html), which then
  communicates with the
  microcontroller?
- ...

My main point is, that the hardware decision has actually nothing to with MATLAB, because the communication will be quite the same whether you go for Microchip or Atmel.